# Data sorting within lists within dictionaries within files

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Although I have searched around I haven't found specific coding relating to my program.

I have a program that loads in a file using pickle, the data is stored as the variable. The data is a dictionary with the values in a list format. I have been assigned a task to sort the dictionary by the highest score for each key and then order the highest scores from highest to lowest.

Also I must present my findings in a user friendly manner, so iterating over loops may be necessary.

Comment: Dictionaries are naturally unordered in Python.  You cannot sort them.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an array from the list with numpy.

```
from numpy import asarray
myarray = asarray(mylist)
```

and then use sort()

or manualy:

```
dict = {'3': 'acs', '2': 'faas', '4': 'abs'}
arr = []
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
    arr.append([k, v])
```

and then `arr.sort()` if its one dimensional, or

```
print sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

if its multidimentional.

**EDIT** after discussion in comments:

Is this what you need?

```
dict = {'Paul' : [ 1, 4, 2], 'Steve' : [2, 3, 1] , 'John' : [3, 2, 4] , 'Thomas' : [4,1, 3] }
arr = []
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
    arr.append([k, v[0], v[1], v[2]])

print sorted(arr, key=lambda y: y[1]) # By first number
print sorted(arr, key=lambda y: y[2]) # By second number
print sorted(arr, key=lambda y: y[3]) # By third number
```

**EDIT2** after further discussion

This is a fix for it. I doubt its the most effective, and i hope that some python gurus will improve on it.

```
dict = {'Paul' : [ 1, 4, 2], 'Steve' : [2, 3] , 'John' : [3, 2, 4] , 'Thomas' : [4,1, 3] }
arr = []
for k, v in dict.iteritems():

    new = [k]

    # add all values to the list 
    for i in range(0, len(v)):
        new.append(v[i])

    # if a list is shorter then 4 items, add zeros to fill it
    while len(new) < 4:
        new.append(0)

    # put the new list in the main list
    arr.append(new)

print arr
print sorted(arr, key=lambda y: y[1]) # By first number
print sorted(arr, key=lambda y: y[2]) # By second number
print sorted(arr, key=lambda y: y[3]) # By third number
```

You can of course change the 0 in the while-loop to 999 if you want the empty ones in the other end of the sorting.

Hopefully it will get it done, all tho it might take some time if the file is large.

Comment: But the dictionaries values are in list format? Has this been taken into consideration? thanks

Comment: can you provide a sample of the dictionary? And what value you will sort after?

Comment: mydict = {'Paul' : [ 1, 4, 2], 'Steve' : [2, 10, 6] }

Comment: ordered by `Person: [x,y,z]` x, y or z?

Comment: yes, however will this still function properly when there are less then three values? thanks for your time